# Deserializing to an F# type using json.net and a json property containing an @ symbol

Tags: f#, json.net

I have a F# type which I deserialize to an object from the content of a HTTP web request. The API which I am calling uses an odata protocol and the content of that request has the following format with contains the key `@odata.context`.

```
{
    "@odata.context":"OData",
    "Value":"token"
}
```

I am using Json.net to deserialize the content back to my F# type, the F# type is as follows

```
type Success = {
    [<JsonProperty(PropertyName = "@odata.context")>]
    ``odata.context``: string;
    Value: string; }
```

`odata.context` is always `null` in this situation.

I have tried both the following (with the @ symbol in the F# type property name) and the result is NULL

```
let test1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Success>("{\"@odata.context\": \"odata.context\", \"Value\": \"token\"}"))
```

(without the @ symbol in the F# type property name) This gets deserialized correctly.

```
let test2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Success>("{\"odata.context\": \"odata.context\", \"Value\": \"token\"}"))
```

I believe this could be to do with the @ symbol in the property name.

Any ideas on a solution would be great.

Comment: What version are you using? https://dotnetfiddle.net/s6W7yJ

Comment: I am using F#3.0 and json.net 6.0.4

Comment: Have you looked at C# answers here at SO since json.net is a .net version and will work with C#?

Comment: you have no way to update the version json.net ?

Comment: Make sure you use `Newtonsoft.Json.8.0.2` - this version of json.net will allow you to deserialise to the object correctly.
I initially tried version `6.0.4` and encountered the same problem as you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have the opportunity to update Json.Net to a newer (e.g. 8.0.2), you can use a [Newtonsoft.Json.Linq](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm).

Example:

```
open System
open Newtonsoft.Json.Linq

type Success = {
    ``odata.context``: string;
    Value: string; }

let json =  "{\"@odata.context\":\"OData\",\"Value\":\"token\"}"

let p = JObject.Parse(json)

{``odata.context`` = p.["@odata.context"] |> string ;Value = p.["Value"] |> string}
|> printfn "%A"
```

Print:

```
{odata.context = "OData";
 Value = "token";}
```

Link:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/SR16Ci